# MVVM binding view to a changeable model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Lets say i have a `ListBox` with multiple model objects, lets call it `person` with the normal values like `name`, `age`, `familiyName` and a list of objects `professions` with arbitrary values.

I want to create an Inspector control now, which shows the values of the selected `person` object but my questing is.

Should the Inspector viewmodel have its own properties (like `SelectedPersonName`, `SelectedPersonAge` etc..) to bind the view to, and update all of them in the event that the selected item in the listbox changes? Or should i implement it by simply having a reference in the inspector viewmodel referencing the selected item in the listbox, ending up with bindings like `{Binding SelectedPerson.name}` `{Binding SelectedPerson.age}` What is best practice here? is there a third way?

Comment: I prefer the second way. when you do PropertyChange("SelectedPerson") all "child" bindings are refresh too like selectedperson.age, selectedperson.name. Its clearer and you dont need a bunch of "stupid" "wrapper" properties

Comment: Both methods are valid. The first is more of the "MVVM purist" approach, and scales better in larger applications with multiple developers, while the 2nd is often easier to build and maintain since there aren't duplicate copies of property. So just pick whichever works best for you, and be consistent about it throughout your application :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way. As long as you notify when the selected person changes, and when the properties on that person change, it will all bind correctly. And you won't need to make a bunch of new viewmodel properties.

Answer (score 1):

you can use one viewModel for each model and initialize them in their constructors like this:

```
public class PersonVm : DependencyObject
{
    public PersonVm(Model.Person model)
    {
        _model = model;
        Name = model.Name;
        Age = model.Age;
        foreach (var professionModel in model.Professions)
        {
            Professions.Add(new ProfessionVm(professionModel));
        }
    }
    Model.Person _model;
    public int Id { get { return _model.Id; } }
    //Name Dependency Property
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(PersonVm), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    //Age Dependency Property
    public int Age
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(AgeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AgeProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AgeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Age", typeof(int), typeof(PersonVm), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

    //Professions Observable Collection
    private ObservableCollection<ProfessionVm> _professions = new ObservableCollection<ProfessionVm>();
    public ObservableCollection<ProfessionVm> Professions { get { return _professions; } }
}
```

This is the viewModel for the whole page or window, you need to create one instance of it in the constructor of the page or window and set DataContext to it after InitializeComponent()

```
public class MainViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public MainViewModel(IEnumerable<Model.Person> models)
    {
        foreach (var personModel in models)
        {
            People.Add(new PersonVm(personModel));
        }
    }
    //People Observable Collection
    private ObservableCollection<PersonVm> _people = new ObservableCollection<PersonVm>();
    public ObservableCollection<PersonVm> People { get { return _people; } }

    //SelectedPerson Dependency Property
    public PersonVm SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return (PersonVm)GetValue(SelectedPersonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedPersonProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedPersonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedPerson", typeof(PersonVm), typeof(MainViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

This way you can bind very easily like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListBox 
        DockPanel.Dock="Left"
        ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}"/>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Professions}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Whatever"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

The benefit of this method is easy Binding. Also the updating of the model is done in the following way:

```
    //Name Dependency Property
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(PersonVm),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
        {
            var vm = (PersonVm)d;
            var val = (string)e.NewValue;
            vm._model.Name = val;
        }));
```